# stack 2.7.1: build fails with resource busy (Text file busy) on Ubuntu

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm unable to do `stack build` for any projects on Ubuntu 20.04 or 18.04 running as a VirtualBox guest on Windows 10. Building fails when trying to rename a temp file: `.stack-cabal-mod11115-0.tmp: rename: resource busy (Text file busy)`

edit: this appears to only happen on VirtualBox shared folders. Stack can successfully build a project in a folder that is not shared with the Windows hot.

I've previously had no issues with 1.9.x  versions of stack in identical environments. At this point I'm not even able to get stack build to compile a new project on a clean Ubuntu installation. If I downgrade to 1.9.3 everything magically works. I've deleted ~.stack and .stack-work folders and retried without success.

Below is the output on a new project using `stack new`. I'm able to use `stack repl`, although I still get an error message about the build failing with

```
vagrant@ubuntu-focal:/vagrant/test$ stack --version
Version 2.7.1, Git revision 8afe0c2932716b0441cf4440d6942c59568b6b19 x86_64 hpack-0.34.4
vagrant@ubuntu-focal:/vagrant/test$ stack setup
Preparing to install GHC (tinfo6) to an isolated location.
This will not interfere with any system-level installation.
Downloaded ghc-tinfo6-8.10.4.
Installed GHC.
stack will use a sandboxed GHC it installed
For more information on paths, see 'stack path' and 'stack exec env'
To use this GHC and packages outside of a project, consider using:
stack ghc, stack ghci, stack runghc, or stack exec

vagrant@ubuntu-focal:/vagrant/test$ stack build
[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( /home/vagrant/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-mPHDZzAJ.hs, /home/vagrant/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-mPHDZzAJ.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling StackSetupShim   ( /home/vagrant/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs, /home/vagrant/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.o )
Linking /home/vagrant/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/tmp-Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_3.2.1.0_ghc-8.10.4 ...
Building all executables for `test' once. After a successful build of all of them, only specified executables will be rebuilt.
test> configure (lib + exe)
Configuring test-0.1.0.0...
/vagrant/test/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-3.2.1.0/.stack-cabal-mod11009-2.tmp: rename: resource busy (Text file                 busy)

vagrant@ubuntu-focal:/vagrant/test$ stack build
Building all executables for `test' once. After a successful build of all of them, only specified executables will be rebuilt.
test> configure (lib + exe)
Configuring test-0.1.0.0...
/vagrant/test/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-3.2.1.0/.stack-cabal-mod11115-0.tmp: rename: resource busy (Text file busy)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce your problem in the `ubuntu:focal` Docker image but it worked for me. Here's what I ran: `apt-get update; apt-get -y install curl; curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh; stack new test; cd test; stack setup; stack build` Can you see if you can reproduce the problem there, with those exact commands?

Comment: Thanks Joseph - interestingly that works if I create the project in my home directory, but if I create the project in the virtualbox folder that is shared with Windows, I run into the error. So it's likely a virtualbox issue, not a stack issue; although I don't know why the problem manifests itself with stack 2.* and not 1.9.*  versions. I've tried a few things with VirtualBox, like downgrading guest additions, but without luck - I'll keep looking, though.

Comment: The fact that it only breaks in VirtualBox shared folders is really important - please edit that detail into the question.

Comment: "The rename fails because oldpath or newpath is a directory that is in use by some process (perhaps as current working  directory,  or as root directory, or because it was open for reading) or is in use by the system (for example as mount point), while the system considers this an error." It would really help if you can find out what exactly the oldpath and newpath are. Can you rename subdirectories in a shared folder?

Comment: Yes, I have no problem from bash renaming subdirectories and files in a shared folder. It's only via stack that the problem exists. And only with versions greater than 1.9.x for me.